# PHP - constructor with SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, constructor

**Option 1:** query the data first and then pass the data to the constructor

**Option 2:** use the constructor to query the data and then fill the properties

---

**Option 1 Example**

```
$val1 = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT val2, val3, val4 FROM table WHERE val1 = '".$val1."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$o = new Class($row['val1'], $row['val2'], $row['val3'], $row['val4']);
```

**Option 2 Example**

```
$val1 = 1;
$o = new Class($val1);

// in Class constructor
public function __construct($val1) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT val2, val3, val4 FROM table WHERE val1 = '".$val1."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $this->val1 = $row['val1'];
    $this->val2 = $row['val2'];
    // etc ...
}
```

**NOTES**

*I am perfectly aware that `mysql_query` is deprecated. Please resist the overwhelming urge to tell me that. These are the reqs for the project.*

I am asking if Option 2 is bad practice or if there are any foreseen predicaments that are overwhelmingly known in the object oriented space. It seems to be the cleaner option to me.

Comment: What are you asking, which is better?

Comment: @JohnCullen Yes, I will update the question to better reflect that.

Comment: I would probably put the query in a function of the class then call that in the constructor so the constructor method itself doesn't get disorganized. This is a highly subjective question though... it doesn't matter much. It's based on your own style preferences. I think making a method is the most readable but others may disagree.

Comment: @JohnCullen Okay, that could work.

Comment: It depends on your design. If you need to be able to create instances that don't always come from the DB, then it should be separate from the constructor. If the class is necessarily tied to the DB, do it in the constructor.

Comment: You say you know mysql_query is deprecated. Should I understand that to mean you *can't* use anything else?

Comment: Before answering this, you should move away from `mysql_` functions and prepare your queries instead of injecting strings directly into the SQL string. I could not resist the urge: why would you worry about construction choices when you have this big issue at hand?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart We use a custom function that uses mysql_query and changing that is above my authority.

Comment: @trincot I had a bet with a coworker that even with my disclaimer, someone would say that. Thanks for the $5. Let's see if I can get another.

Comment: The disclaimer does not help. It is our duty to point at the weakest point of your code. Anyway your question is for CodeReview, not for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please provide contact details of your PM.

Comment: The constructor is better. If the data is always going to be retrieved the same way, it makes more sense to minimize the constructor's argument count. But you might want to throw an exception if there is are any database errors, since someone might instantiate that object when the db is down or no connection parameters are where they are expected, or whatever.

Comment: Why are you using Object Orientated PHP but *not* using Object Orientated MySQLi ?

Comment: Do you understand how to use mysqli and the equivalent functions for mysql extension? Maybe it would save you a lot of grief just to ask the question using mysqli and then convert as needed.

Comment: `I am asking if Option 2 is bad practice ` - you're standing in a bucket of water holding up a long metal stick in a thunder storm, and asking us if the fact you blasphemed against God today makes it more likely you're going to get struck by lightning. Please fix your more important issues before even considering approaching this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show this to whoever is in charge.
[image]

---

But anyways back to your question.

As much as I hate to answer like this, I think option 2 definitely makes the code cleaner, but you can also make it even more clean, by creating a method in the class that returns what you're looking for.

```
<?php

class SomeName extends DBClass
{
    // No need for the construct in this case

    public function fetchResults($val)
    {
        $notSoDirtyVal = mysql_real_escape_string($val);

        $query = "SELECT val2, val3, val4 FROM table WHERE val1 = '".$notSoDirtyVal."'"// Make sure you escape, sanitize, and clean this!!!!!

        $stmt = mysql_query($query); 

        $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        return $results;
    }
}
?>
```

On your other file you can then do this

```
<?php
$value1 = 1;

$o = new SomeName;
$results = $o->fetchResults($value1);
```

Comment: There's even a [whole site](http://bobby-tables.com/) dedicated to that very subject as well as [other resources](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) as I'm positive this code-base would hard-fail even the most superficial of security audits.

Comment: It's also important to *escape*. Sanitization is a separate, optional step. Escaping is not.

Comment: It'd be better to include a call to `mysql_real_escape_string` because you have to practice what you preach. When someone falls out of a time machine with code from the 1870s you need to speak their language.

Comment: @tadman I can't code like this.. It hurts..

Answer (score 0):

Well... You have bigger problems than where to put your query but...

I would say option 1 is best because you could instantiate that class somewhere else with data *not* from a DB.

In other words, that class is not constrained to the DB.

Comment: That class will always be instantiated with data from the DB.

Comment: Thinking that way will eventually force some other poor employee to use the DB against their will much like the decision to use `mysql_query` in *some function* is forcing you to write patchy code.

Comment: Having a class that is a curl wrapper forces the employee to use curl and make http requests. I've always struggled with understanding the line between an class that constructs an object that is what it is and does what it needs to efficiently and a class that allows for dependency injection. At some point, don't you just have to give up on constructors altogether to ensure full injection-ability?

Comment: @Anthony IMHO, when you write code that has even an infinitesimally small chance of eventually becoming someone else's responsibility, *you* have the responsibility to make that code as *clear* and *maintainable* as possible. In your example, I would not have made a wrapper for curl, I would have made an interface exposing only the most basic methods we need to get the job done be it with curl, or whatever else.

Comment: @Anthony I could go on for hours about this topic. I am a huge believer in DI and decoupling everything in general :). If you'd like to chat about it (I certainly would), let me know!

Comment: That does sound like my kind of party. I specifically encountered something recently that got me thinking about this scenario (and where it seemed like dependency injection wouldn't be an option, and I wasn't convinced it should be). If I run into again, I'll hit you up. I'd like to have an example or two that are realistic rather than me just playing the dumb guy who asks the easy questions to socrates just so socrates can explain a concept.